# Missing ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application template for Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I just installed Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop, but I cannot find the template ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application anywhere.  I have tried everything and I don't know how to get it to show up.  Here is what my screen currently looks like:

[Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 - New Project Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPiYY.png)

How can I get the template to show up?

Comment: which type of installation you choose while installation typical or custom ?

Comment: It didn't give me an option.  When the popup came up, it just gave two checkboxes: (1) to agree to the terms and conditions, and (2) to opt in to provide feedback (which I unchecked).  After I clicked on the checkbox to agree to the terms, an Install link appeared and then it just started installing.

Comment: either visual studio express 2012 has no feature of mvc4 so you my try to install  standalone MVC 4 Installer .

Comment: I believe I already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: I'm going to try installing Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 instead and see if it's listed in there.

Comment: That did the trick.